# Programatically retrieve files uploaded to a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Looking to automate the processing of data in a spreadsheet generated by google forms; specifically, I want to attach the files uploaded to the form to outgoing emails as attachments. The files can be synced to a local folder for the program to access, but the google form only has a url for each uploaded file.
What would be the most efficient way to determine which of the files uploaded correspond with each form submission and its corresponding link?

Edit: my research indicates that I may be able to use an identifier from the url to see which document it is through an apps api. Another thought was to scrape the html from the linked webpage and then to glean the file name from somewhere in the html here it hopefully occurs with regularity. 
Then I could use the filename to construct a filepath to the synced folder on my local machine or would it be better to use the drive api to manipulate the file into an email attachment?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: my research indicates that I may be able to use an identifier from the url to see which document it is through an apps api. Another thought was to scrape the html from the linked webpage and then to glean the file name from somewhere in the html here it hopefully occurs with regularity. Then I could use the filename to construct a filepath to the synced folder on my local machine or would it be better to use the drive api to manipulate the file into an email attachment?